# Get the morphMany relationship to a model from the user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let say i have the following;

User Model;

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{

  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Socials\Post');
  }
}
```

Post Model;

```
class Post extends Model 
{

  public function comments()
  {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Socials\Comment', 'commentable');
  }
```

Comment model;

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentable()
    {
     return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

When i used `$user = User::find($id);` and `$user->posts()`, it returns all the post of the user, but if i used this method `$user->posts()->comments()` It return this message `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::comments does not exist`.

The question is how can i get all the comments of the user on the said post?

Comment: what about `$user->posts()->with('comments')->get();`

Comment: You can find this very well explained here-> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations. If you still have problems please show your table structure

Comment: Without seeing your DB I can already tell you that your Comment Model isn't well defined. Your function should be posts() { return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'commentable');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$user->posts()->comments();
```

to:

```
$user->posts->pluck('comments')->collapse();
```

The method itself returns an instance of Eloquent's query builder allowing you to add to or edit the query if you want. However, if you don't want to edit the query you can access the relationships as properties and Laravel will handle to execution of the query.

Essentially, `$user->posts` is actually turning into `$user->posts()->get()` in the background.

Credit to @JonasStaudenmeir.

Comment: It throws `Property [comments] does not exist on this collection instance`

Comment: Use `$user->posts->pluck('comments')->collapse();`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Of course...I feel a little silly now haha. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @RossWilson